# How to handle dynamic xpath in python selenium?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have tried to handle the dynamic xpath and css selector by many ways, but not getting the correct solution. Please help me out regarding this issue.

xpath is `//*[@id="product_properties_attributes_15434094021_value"]`

Here the number "15434094021" is changing every time at the time of opening the page.
I have also tried with css selector by it is not solved. 
I have tried with "Starts with" & "Contains", but not solved.
Before the same type of questions are posted and answered also. But this question is not solved and that is why I have posted this question.

getting this error for starts-with

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid
>   selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   //*div[starts-with(@id,'product_properties_attributes_')] because of
>   the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on
>   'Document': The string
>   '//*div[starts-with(@id,'product_properties_attributes_')]' is not a
>   valid XPath expression.

And this below-mentioned error for using "contains" -

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid
>   selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   //*div[contains(@id,'product_properties_attributes_') and
>   contains(@id,'_value')] because of the following error: SyntaxError:
>   Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
>   '//*div[contains(@id,'product_properties_attributes_') and
>   contains(@id,'_value')]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: Could you please tell me which URL I need to share?

Comment: The url where you are trying to work with these elements of dynamic xpath

Comment: As uid and pw required to open the link - it cannot be shared. I have given the xpath.

Comment: @kamal - probably this can help you to find out...                                      <input id="product_properties_attributes_15438407881_value" name="product[properties_attributes][15438407881][value]" required="required" size="30" type="text">

Comment: I can see two issues from your traces, 1. Quoting issues(reason for syntaxerror): You have to use double quotes for strings inside single quotes and vice versa. 2. The element you shared in last comment is an `input` element, but according to traces, you are looking for `div` element.

Comment: Now, I am giving this  -  productSKU = driver.find_element_by_id("[contains(@id,'product_properties_attributes_')]")  but it is showing that "Unable to locate element".

Comment: I don't think use of `contains` like this with `find_element_by_id` works. You can try `find_element_by_xpath("//*input[contains(@id, 'product_properties_attributes_')]")`

Comment: @kamal , Now I am getting this error - selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*input[contains(@id, 'product_properties_attributes_')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*input[contains(@id, 'product_properties_attributes_')]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Please try this: `find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'product_properties_attributes_')]")` I had added the * by mistake

Comment: Getting this error - selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Comment: It is hard to help you without the full html, one suggestion: please check if this element is inside `iframe` tag

Comment: This is the html for that field - <input id="product_properties_attributes_15445104131_value" name="product[properties_attributes][15445104131][value]" required="required" size="30" type="text">     - the big number is changing all the time...

Comment: You are seeing a `InvalidSelectorException` unless you update the question with relevant HTML this question can't be answered.

Comment: This is the required HTML file ...please check...         <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="product_properties_attributes_15446016661_SKU *">Sku *</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input id="product_properties_attributes_15446016661_value" name="product[properties_attributes][15446016661][value]" required="required" size="30" type="text">
                      </div>
                    </div>

Comment: Found any way to solve this?